# How can I parse the mod-rewrite url variable in a block after appending extension and checking if it exists

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The first task in my mod-rewrite is to check if the page exists after appending .php to the request. If it doesn't, I want to append the value input after the forward slash to a search page (i.e. index.php?search={input variable}
**The problem is that it's appending ".php" to the input variable.**

I have tried a multitude of variable permutations, but can't get it to work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/?$ index.php?search=$1 [L]
```

My GET variable on the index page for non-matching requests shows the appended ".php". If mod-rewrite did if/else, I'd be ok. My ignorance precludes me

**For example:**

This Works: [domain]/login shows the [domain]/login.php because I have login.php as a page

This is the problem: [domain]/abc123 properly goes to index.php/?search=abc123.php (search _GET variable contains the php extension).

Note: If I try only the second block (don't rewrite to compare to existing .php page) it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [END]

RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ index.php?search=$1 [END]
```